# Magento 2: Import multiple select attribute values using CSV

Tags: magento2, import, csv, multiselect-attribute

How can we import multiple select attribute values using CSV ?

For example SKU "test" has two values for attribute "xyz" - "val1" and "val2".

When I use both value as `val1<space><comma><space>val2` , import throws error:

> 1. Value for 'xyz' attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin rows ....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by just add multiple values by any separator and add that separator in `Multiple value separator` field.
like this

```
val1|val2|val3
```

check this screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/ics5ur

if you still face the issue then un-check `Fields enclosure` checkbox.

Comment: We had tried with a semicolon `;` before and failed. It does not work with a semicolon as `multiple value separator`. But it does work with the pipe, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Not working in 2.3.1

Comment: Not woking M2 2.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 - We have multiple options for separating your custom attributes like

**USING COMMA**

```
attribute_code1 = custom_attribute_value1 , attribute_code2 = custom_attribute_value2 , gon on...
```

**USING VERTICAL BAR**

```
attribute_code1 = custom_attribute_value1 | attribute_code2 = custom_attribute_value2 | gon on...
```

**USING COLON**

```
attribute_code1 = custom_attribute_value1 : attribute_code2 = custom_attribute_value2 : gon on...
```

We have **Multiple value separator** option in admin panel, below-attached screenshot for your reference

[image]

**--- More Description -----**

Magento 2 -  When you are export product CSV, created product custom attributes comes under "additional_attributes" column in CSV file.

**If you have multiple custom attribute, which would be separated by commas in same "additional_attributes" column**

**additional_attributes** column in product csv file

```
Product 1 : attribute_code1 = custom_attribute_value1 , attribute_code2 = custom_attribute_value2 , gon on...
Product 2 : attribute_code1 = custom_attribute_value1 , attribute_code2 = custom_attribute_value2 , go on...
```

Finally, you can proceed with normal magento2 import process, you can see respective product attributes value is updated...

**Notes : Magento 2 custom attributes value comes under "additional_attributes" column in csv file**

Answer (score 1):

I tried like following

in "additional_attributes" I put values like for my custom made multiple select attribute filter_color,
filter_color=SILVER | GOLD | BLUE

Also "Fields enclosure" check box is already unchecked.

Also put "|" in "Multiple value separator" while importing.

even then the following error displayed while importing 
Value for 'filter_color' attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin
But for the rows which contains values like "filter_color=SILVER" (SINGLE VALUES) it shows correct

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: When I removed the space near to the "|" symbol it works. Even then it is not showed in left side filter options.

Comment: This is also resolved after doing reindexing

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by passing your multiselect attribute code and its values separated by **|** symbol in CSV.
For example, here I'm passing different attributes of different types inside **additional_attributes** CSV column

```
date_time=7/21/23,material=cotton,size=large,usage=Travel|Sports|Office|Casual
```

CSV:
[image: Column with attributes in CSV]

**usage** - multiselect attribute with various values. This attribute is already created. Import does not create attributes! During import you just assign attribute values to the imported product.

Result (imported product page with attributes in admin area):
[image: Imported product page with imported attributes]